# Calculate the expected value of the following betting strategy.

Tags: probability

I am trying to calculate the expected value of the following game: we first start off with ten 10 in a row. Now the probability to win is $p(w)$ and the probability to lose is $p(l)=1-p(w)$.

If we now start the game, we will bet the sum of the *first* and the *last* number in the row, in this case we will bet $20$. If we win, we will double our profit, so we get $40$, which is $20$ profit. If we lose, we simply lose our bet and we append to the row what we have betted. So if we lose in the first round, we have lost 20 and we have appended the number 20 to our row. We stop if there are no numbers left or there is only one number left.

I am so suprised that this simple strategy makes it so hard to calculate the expected value. But here is what I have tried:

Given that $k$ is the total number of rounds of the game, we can do the following:

$k=5$ optimal case we win every time: $p(w)^5(20\cdot 5)$

$k=6$ we have $({6 \choose 1}-1)p(w)^5\cdot p(l)(10+20\cdot 5)$

$k=7$ not possible.

$k=8$ we get $({8 \choose 2}-{7\choose 1})p(w)^6p(l)^2\cdot(10\cdot 2 + 20 \cdot 4)$

Now this is all good and I see the pattern so I can write this down in a summation, but there is one case that I can't deal with: what if we lose so many times, that our tens are gone and we are left with a row of the "betting" numbers? For example:

we have: 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

we win once: 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

we win 2x: 10 10 10 10 10 10

we win 3x: 10 10 10 10

we win 4x: 10 10

Now let's say we win 4 times, so we get:

New row: 10 10

Now let's say we lose 5 times, we get:

we have WWWWL: 10 10 20

we have WWWWLL: 10 10 20 30

we have WWWWLLL: 10 10 20 30 40

we have WWWWLLLL: 10 10 20 30 40 50

we have WWWWLLLLL: 10 10 20 30 40 50 60

Now if we win 3 times we are done and left with 30.

We have WWWWLLLLLW: 10 20 30 40 50

We have WWWWLLLLLWW: 20 30 40

We have WWWWLLLLLWWW: 30

So in this case we end with losing 30 in my last term, but the question is how can I find this "loss"?

If I have made any mistakes, please let me know. This is a problem proposed by a friend of mine, but we both could not solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Either I don't fully understand your strategy or there's some mistake in the example. I say that because I feel that when losing 5 times in a row, the remaining row should be: $10\ 10\ 10\ 10\ 60$, since whenever you bet, apparently, you remove the values you'd used (and add a new one if you lost the bet). All together, what means is that even if losing all bets, at most you'll play 9 bets. Could you confirm this or explain how you ended up with your string? Thanks

Comment: Dear Albert, first I would like to thank you for your comment and I understand your confusion. I have written out the entire gameplay of my example.

Comment: Ok, it's understood now. Maybe you'd like to clarify the first instructions, so it explains that numbers are only removed when won. Still, now I can begin to find a solution to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is basicaly the same [strategy](http://www.roulettestrategy.net/strategy/martingale/) than we saw in roulette in which *you always win*. It basically doesn't work. And it doesn't because you're asuming here you have unlimited money to bet and that the betting system will accept a bet no matter how big it is.

So, if you want to have a real probability question, you should add some limit to your betting strategy. Otherwise it's simply impossible to apply.

Still, what would the $E[X]$ be? (where $X$ are your earnings)

$E[X]=20\times 5=100$

Yes, $E[X]=100$ regardless the number of bets you did. Why? Basically what you are doing here is, whenever you lose $\alpha$ you later will bet $2\alpha$ (once because you did not remove any of the numbers from the row and once more because you added it to the end of the row). So sooner or later, if there's no limit of any kind, you'll find yourself winning $2\alpha$, getting back the $\alpha$ you lost and winning an extra $\alpha$ that in the end will be equal to your initial bet.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Albert, perhaps I misunderstood the answer, but what do you mean with limit? The limit is simply when the row of numbers end or we are left with one number. I agree that when the number of losses are even, that they simply cancel out, however if the number of losses are uneven, it will be impossible to cancel the remaining number and therefore the expected value will be less than our approximation, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Snowflake Imagine you keep betting and losing, and eventually you have to bet $\$10^{100}$. Will you be able to do so? If you want to work only theoretically, assuming you can bet any conceivable amount, then, as said, $E[X]=100$. Otherwise, you have some limit. One example for that would be that you have a limited budget of money you can bet before being bankrupt.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand your point. Thank you!